# Update list on checking boxes

Tags: c#, wpf, list, checkbox, mvvm

I have a `list<Month> months` that contains 12 month objects with a name string that has the name of the month (e.g. januari), and a `list<Month> selectedMonths` that i'd like to add to the months that are selected by the user with a checkbox, and remove them when the box is unticked.

In XAML I have:

```
<StackPanel>
  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding monthCheck}" Content="Januari"/>
  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding monthCheck}" Content="Februari"/>
  [etc...]
  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding monthCheck}" Content="November"/>
  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding monthCheck}" Content="December"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Right now in my viewmodel i have:

```
private bool _monthCheck;
public bool monthCheck{
get{ return _monthCheck; }
set{
   _monthCheck = value;
   OnPropertyChanged("maandCheck");
   }
```

Right now, if i click any of the checkboxes, all 12 of them will change with the one i click (understandable, they're all bound to the same bool); i'd like it to be that when i tick a box, it checks the `Content` of the checkbox, and adds the appropriate month from the `months` to the `selectedMonths`. 
How would i do this?
Can i do this with just code in the `monthCheck` setter? Something like:

```
set{
   _montcheck = value;
   if(value){
      somehow get Content
      select month with name = content from months
      selectedMonths.add(thatMonth)
      only check the appropriate box
   }

   if(!value){
      somehow get Content
      select month with that name
      selectedMonths.remove(thatMonth)
      only uncheck the appropriate box
   }
   OnPropertyChanged("maandCheck");
}
```

Not sure how i should go about this.

Comment: well you just need to make 12 bools, same as what you're doing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view model should have a collection of Month objects that an ItemsControl in your view can bind to:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Months}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The view model, with a method that returns the selected Months:

```
public class Month
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Month> Months { get; } = new List<Month>
    {
        new Month { Name="January" },
        new Month { Name="February" },
        new Month { Name="March" },
        new Month { Name="April" },
        new Month { Name="May" },
        new Month { Name="June" },
        new Month { Name="July" },
        new Month { Name="August" },
        new Month { Name="September" },
        new Month { Name="October" },
        new Month { Name="November" },
        new Month { Name="December" },
    };

    public IEnumerable<Month> SelectedMonths
    {
        get { return Months.Where(m => m.IsSelected); }
    }
}
```

This example misses a mechanism that actually notifies the UI about changes of the collection of selected months, but from the question it is unclear whether that is required at all.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what your code does? I'm still rather new to C# and WPF. As for needing to notify the UI; the `month` class contains several variables relating to the climate for that month (i.e. average temperature, wind speed) - When the user hits a button, the app has to iterate over the selected months and do a series of calculations with the data in those months. I have that part set up and working, just need to make it so that the list of months that's iterated over works.

Comment: @Clemens honestly, your answer is 100% better than mine, but for someone starting with WPF I think a bit too difficult to understand.

Comment: It binds an ItemsControl to a collection of Month object. The element(s) in the ItemTemplate bind to the individual items of the collection. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) for all the details.

Comment: @Siegfried.V That is entirely wrong. Your answer just shows how it should not be done at all. If you learn WPF, using ItemsControls is essential stuff.

Comment: @Clemens I've updated my request for clarification a bit. Any more advice is welcome!

Comment: @RKeul The collection of selected months is evaluated whenever you access the SelectedMonths property. You can easily do that in a Button Click handler.

Comment: @Clemens implemented it, works like a charm. Thanks!. For future reference, how would i go about implementing, say a ListBox that updates to show the checked months whenever someone ticks one of the checkboxes?

Comment: The standard MVVM approach would be to make the Month class implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. The IsSelected property setter would fire the interface's PropertyChanged event. The main ViewModel would register PropertyChanged event handlers on each if its Month elements, which would update an ObservableCollection of selected Months or selected month names.

Comment: Thank you! You've been a great help!